# Add setter to an singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, getter-setter

I have a singleton class like this

```
public class Service{

// SingletonHolder is a container class to hold singleton instance 
 private static final SingletonHolder<A> singleton = new SingletonHodler<>(new Service());

 private Service(){
}
  public static Service getInstance(){

//.instance() is a method in SingletonHolder to return singleton instance
    return singleton.instance();
  }

 //Method to start the Service class
  public void start(){
   // start the service
   // get the initial configuration and use the configuration value to speify a URL, something like:
   String initialConfiguration = Configuration.getSettings();
   TargetUrl = initialConfiguration.get.......
}

}
```

Another class for configuration. This class will initialize the configuration and use configurationUpdate() to get the updated configuration value.

```
public class Configuration{


    public void configurationInitialize(){

    // initialize the configuration and get the value
    initialConfigValue = ..........    
}


   // Method to update configuration
   public void configurationUpdate(){

   // some mehtod which will get the updated configuration value
   String updateConfiguration = .............

    }    
  //method to retrun configuration settings
  public static String getSettings(){.........}
}
```

Now I want to get the initial configuration first. Then, get the updatedValue if the configuration is changed.

One of my options is to add a setter method to the Service class. And call the setter method in the configurationUpdate() method of Configuration class, pass the UpdateVlaue to that setter.

I am not sure if it is the proper way to do that. If I add the setter method, is it still a singleton? Will this operation cause any problem?
Thank you very much!!!

Edit: Another initialization class will call the configuration class to initialize configuration and also call Service.getInstance().start()

Comment: (1) From current description I understand that you need to start the service with an initial configuration, then use it and when the configuration changes you want to update the service instance with the new configuration. Is this what it needs to be implemented? (2) how is the initial configuration passed to the service instance? from the current description the service instance does not use the configuration. (3) which is the purpose of the SingletonHolder? if is for lazy initialisation of the service instance then it needs to be reworked

Comment: @Valentin Carnu You are right. Basically, I only read the initial configuration value and used that value to get targetUrl. But now, the configuration value might be changed during the project running. So I need to handle updated configuration value and update the targetUrl properly.

Comment: Do you use a dependency injection framework? Something like [Spring framework](https://spring.io)

Comment: @ValentinCarnu For now, I just use the static method getSettings() to get the configuration instance and use it in the start() method. In another initialization class, it will initialize the configuration and call Service.getInstance().start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure if it is the proper way to do that. If I add the setter method, is it still a singleton? Will this operation cause any problem?

It will still be a singleton. If all the threads should use same targetUrl then it should be fine. If each thread should use it's own targetUrl then a setter changing the value of the targetUrl field will affect all the threads.

Not sure if this is what is needed, but maybe it give some useful hints.

Instead of passing the configuration to the service instance, make the configuration available via a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and a static method so the Service class can retrieve the configuration when it needs it (see Configuration#settingsHolder variable and the Configuration#getSettings method)

NOTE: I didn't use a SingletonHolder as the purpose of it is not clear to me (the way it is described it doesn't provide lazy initialisation and usually an instance holder is used for lazy initialisation purpose)

```
public class Service {

    private static final Service INSTANCE = new Service();

    private static final ThreadLocal<TargetUrl> TARGET_URL_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal();

    private Service() {

    }

    public static Service getInstance() {
        return Service.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void start() {
        Settings initialConfiguration = Configuration.getSettings();
        TARGET_URL_HOLDER.set(initialConfiguration.getTargetUrl());
        // some more stuff before starting
    }

    public void reinitialize() {
        Settings updatedConfiguration = Configuration.getSettings();
        TARGET_URL_HOLDER.set(updatedConfiguration.getTargetUrl());
        .......
    }
}

public class Settings {
    private TargetUrl targetUrl;

    public TargetUrl getTargetUrl() {
        return this.targetUrl;
    }

    public void setTargetUrl(TargetUrl targetUrl) {
        this.targetUrl = targetUrl;
    }
}

public class Configuration {
    // use threadLocal to store the settings instance so it can be retrieved via a static method (e.g. getSettings)
    private static ThreadLocal<Settings> SETTINGS_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void initialize() {

        // initialize the configuration
        Settings initialSettings = ..........
        SETTINGS_HOLDER.set(initialSettings);    
    }

    // Method to update configuration
    public void update() {
        // some method which will get the updated configuration value
       Settings updatedSettings = .............
       SETTINGS_HOLDER.set(updatedSettings);
    }

    //method to retrun configuration settings
    public static Settings getSettings() {
        return SETTINGS_HOLDER.get();
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.initialize();

        Service service = Service.getInstance();
        service.start();
        // use service instance
        ...................

        configuration.update();

        service.reinitialize();

        // keep using the service instance
       .................
    }
}
```

Depending on the use case, if all the threads must use same targetUrl, it might also be implemented using a static variable of type [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) instead of a static variable of type ThreadLocal

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question. If I add a setter method in the Service class and call the setter method in the configurationInitialize(). Something like Service.getInstance().setter(initialConfigValue). Then call the setter in the configurationUpdate(). Something like Service.getInstance().setter(updateConfiguration). Is that ok to do that?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. I'm not sure about the name of the setter method, if the method only updates the configuration then is ok, otherwise if the method updates the configuration and does some other computation too then I would use a different name than setter, maybe something like `reinitialise`